# using mobx with react functional components and without decorators

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to get MobX to work with functional components in react. I want to do this without having to use decorators. I have set up an app with create-react-app, added MobX and MobX-react as dependencies. 
However, I can't seem to get observables working within functional components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { extendObservable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const Test = () => {
    extendObservable(this, {
        button: false
    });

    const handleB1 = () => {
        this.button = false;
    }

    const handleB2 = () => {
        this.button = true;
    }

    const getButton2 = () => {
        console.log('button2');
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={handleB2}>Button 2</button>
        );
    };

    const getButton1 = () => {
        console.log('button1');
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={handleB1}>Button 1</button>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {this.button ? getButton1() : getButton2()}
        </div>
    )
};

export default observer(Test);
```

Clicking the button I would expect the component to get rerendered due to the observable being changed, but I get an error:

```
×
Error: [mobx] Invariant failed: Side effects like changing state are not 
allowed at this point. Are you trying to modify state from, for example, the render 
function of a React component? Tried to modify: ObservableObject@2.button
```

I have tried declaring the observable as part of a functional component or before like this:

```
const buttonState = () => {
    extendObservable(this, {
        button: false
    });
}
```

but in both cases I could not get the component to rerender or i was not sure if the observable was actually correctly set.

If i write the whole thing as a class like this it works perfectly

```
import React from 'react';
import { extendObservable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        extendObservable(this, {
            button: false
        });
    }

    handleB1 = () => {
        this.button = false;
    }

    handleB2 = () => {
        this.button = true;
    }

    getButton2 = () => {
        console.log('button2');
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleB2}>Button 2</button>
        );
    };

    getButton1 = () => {
        console.log('button1');
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleB1}>Button 1</button>
        );
    };

    render = () => {
        return  (
        <div>
            {this.button ? this.getButton1() : this.getButton2()}
        </div>
        )
    }
};

export default observer(Test);
```

Comment: A functional component is just a function, so `extendObservable(this, ... )` will not work as in the class example. Why do you want to use a functional component if you have state?

Comment: well i wanted to use the functional component because I find the syntax easier to read. Originally I wrote this for a simple delete button which, upon click would expand to show two button, one to confirm, one to delete. I thought having a state inside a simple component like that made sense, but now that you pretty much spelled it out for me, it actually makes sense now.

Comment: Though, after looking at the documentation again, this section seemed kind of what I wanted to do: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html#creating-observable-properties-without-decorators

Comment: That would work great if you had a `Timer` object, but I'm afraid it will not work as intended if that would have been a React `TimerView`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In React, functional components are not persistent. They run from top to bottom, return some JSX, rinse and repeat.

```
let i = 0;

const FunctionalComp = (props) => {
  const foo = props.foo.toUpperCase();
  return <span>Rendered {i++} times. {foo}</span>;
}
```

All this functional component will ever do is synchronously create the value `foo` and then return the span. When this component's parent re-renders, this component will do the same exact same, but with potentially new values.

It can never do anything else, and that is why it is powerful. That is why we can call it a *functional* component: Because it only depends on the values provided to it, because it does not cause side effects that would alter the direction of the rest of the application, and because given the same arguments, this function will produce the same result for the rest of eternity.

Predictable = powerful.

Now, a class component holds persistent state. It constructs, initializes its state, methods, and properties, and then renders and returns JSX. The class (object) still exists in memory, so all of the values and methods on it exist too.

The methods of class component are not so predictable.

```
class Foo {
  name = 'tommy';

  getUpperName() {
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
  }

  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

`Foo.getUpperName` will not produce the same result every time it is ever used with the same arguments (hint: it doesn't accept any arguments and depends on the context around it to determine its result), so other pieces of the application may change `Foo.name` and, essentially, control `Foo.getUpperName`'s outcome, potentially by accident.

The class can update its own state, causing itself and all children components to re-compute their JSX returns.

In a plain arrow function, after it returns, all that exists is the return value that it produces and the function statement (declaration). Nothing in between.

All this said, the functional component has no `this` bound to it. (That is a no-no in functional programming.) It will never have state.

So you can not do anything with `this` inside of a functional component and it can not hold observable values because every time it re-renders it would re-instantiate each of those values.

In your example above, even if `this` did refer to `Test`, this is what would happen:

1. Test would create the observable value `button` as `false`.
2. Test would render the button, which you would then click.
3. Test would create the observable value `button` as `false`.
4. Test would render the button, which you would then click.
5. Test would create the observable value `button` as `false`.
6. Test would render the button, which you would then click.

So on and so forth.

In MobX, your observables need to live on a persistent data structure and be passed into your render functions that return UI markup.

```
const store = observable({
  name: 'tommy'
});

const changeName = () => store.name = store.name.split('').reverse().join('');

const Foo = observer((props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={changeName}>{store.name}'s button</button>
  )
});
```

This is not a great pattern, as neither `Foo` nor `changeName` are pure, this code would work, at least.

You need to do something like so:

```
const store = () => {
  const self = {};

  self.actions = {
    setName: action((name) =>  self.name = name);
  }

  return extendObservable(self, { name: 'tommy' });
}

const App = (props) => {
    return <span><Foo store={store} /></span>
}

const Foo = observer((props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.store.actions.setName}>
      {store.name}'s button
    </button>
  )
})
```

Again, this is not an ideal implementation, but it would work, and I am at work and have to get back to what they pay me to do. ;)

Comment: your point about FP for class components is wrong because useState acts the same way as Observable.

Comment: *this is not an ideal implementation* - any suggestion (link, maybe) for a good one?